# Where do the Green Party and NHA differ on NHS policy?

Tags: united-kingdom, healthcare, policy

Both the British Green Party and the National Health Action (NHA) Party stand for an end to privatisation of health service provision and support services. The NHA is a single-issue party while the Greens have a wider manifesto.

Both parties have broadly similar ideologies when it comes to the National Health Service, but are there any specific policy differences between them and if so, what are they?

(I don't want this to be a "list" question so if there are many, one or two examples will suffice!)

Comment: *"I don't want this to be a "list" question so if there are many, one or two examples will suffice!"* So you don't want a list in *one* answer, you want a list distributed over *multiple* answers? That would be even worse, IMO.

Comment: @philipp That's not really what I want; I'm aware list questions are often closed on SE so was trying to avoid that. I'm really after a succinct outline of any major policy differences rather than a big list of minor ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two parties are broadly in sympathy on most topics. The National Health Action Party is by no means a one-issue party, although the NHS ethos informs its thinking in other areas too such as housing and environmental issues. Having been formed by doctors and other health professionals, it has an in-depth understanding of what has been going wrong in the NHS and how to fix it. But in general Greens and NHAP work well together.